# insert the last 30 date in an oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a table where we have one date column. I need to insert the date from yesterday to yesterday-30 days.Table output should look like this

[image]

There is one way where I can create a table and enter each date individually.

```
create table test 
(

c_date date
)

insert into test values (trunc(sysdate)-1);
insert into test values (trunc(sysdate)-2);
insert into test values (trunc(sysdate)-3);
insert into test values (trunc(sysdate)-4);
insert into test values (trunc(sysdate)-5);
.....
insert into test values (trunc(sysdate)-30);
```

what is the efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a hierarchical query such as

```
CREATE TABLE test AS
 SELECT TRUNC(sysdate) - level AS "date"
   FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <= 30
```

or preferably use directly the query without the first line(*CTAS*) as a subquery for your main query